# How do I compare if 2 variables are true in an else if statement jS?

Tags: javascript, operators

I'm trying to do the following:

```
    if (x) {
       // then this
    } else if (calcDifference = 7) && (currentCMSI = 7) { // problem line
       // then this
    } else if {
      // then this
   }
```

Or this:

```
    if (x) {
       // then this
    } else if (calcDifference = 7 && currentCMSI = 7) { // problem line
       // then this
    } else if {
      // then this
    }
```

But I keep getting errors, what's the correct syntax for comparing if 2 different variables are both true in an else if statement?

Comment: An `if` statement has one set of outer parenthesis. All of the conditional logic must be within `(` and `)`. The logic itself can have as many additional `( )` as you need.

Comment: `} else if {}` should just be `} else {}` for the final catch all, or removed all together if no logic falls within the last `{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither!

`=` is an assignment operator

`==` is used to compare two variables

So to answer your question, the second suggestion but with`==`

> `if (calcDifference == 7 && currentCMSI == 7)`

Comment: and the last one should be only `else {...}` (not `else if {...}`

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for :)